# Is there an easy way to determine the masculine, feminine or neuter forms of a noun?

Tags: noun

I am just beginning to learn German and I was wondering if there was an easy way to determine if a noun was masculine, feminine or neuter? Or is it one of those things that I just learn over time?

Comment: No, you have to learn the gender for each word - ideally not over time, but right at the beginning. There are _some_ rules, e.g depending on suffix, but they generally don't help a lot when speaking, and they don't cover too many nouns either.

Comment: As Gerhard said, some words, such as the ones ending in **-ung** share the same genus. Similarly, words that come from other languages with a similar morphology do not (normally) change Genus when they enter the German language. An example for this is indeed *Genus*, which comes from Latin and remained a neuter noun. This can be helpful if you know Greek and Latin. There are some other "groups" which have a single Genus, but I personally suggest to just learn them by heart. Usually, the grouping part comes *after* having learnt the words, and patterns are helpful later on.